# Android functions must be marked with the @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, composable

I have a @Composable function that works perfectly with single element inside using the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial). However, by adding `LocalInspectionMode.current` or other elements, such as, `column`, it produces a strange error.

```
@Composable
fun MessageCard(name: String){
    if(LocalInspectionMode.current){
    Text("Hello $name!")
    } else {
        Text("Goodbye $name!")
    }
}
```

or

```
@Composable
fun MessageCard(msg: Message){
    Column {
        Text("Hello ${msg.author}!")
        Text("Hello ${msg.author}!")
    }
}
```

The error message:

> Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the
> @Composable annotation

Obviously, the function does contain the `@Composable` annotation.
Any help? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any errors with both code blocks. Make sure you have latest versions and correctly setup everything according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/adding). Also try creating a blank Compose app with Android Studio to see if the warning is still there.

Comment: Please try to build, then post the error output

Comment: I had same issue when i was add column in the code i got same error which you have posted. and i wasted my 2 day for this but issue not solve. and Last i have create new project with compose activity and this default created compose code getting not error with column element. so what i do copy same all dependency to My project and issue is solved. you should try once with this crate default compose activity project.